# About $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{7})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{7})\subset \mathbb{C}$. To compute $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$, I know that

\begin{align*}
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]&=2\\
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}):\mathbb{Q}]&=3.
\end{align*}

Can I say that $$2<[K:\mathbb{Q}]\leq 6$$ and because $2\not |$ $3,5$ and $3\not | $ $4$, then $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=6$?

And, if $\gamma=\sqrt{5}\sqrt[3]{7}$, the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$ would be $p(x)=x^6-5^37^2?$

I'm a bit insecure about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt5,\sqrt[3]7)$ then $|K:\Bbb Q|=|K:\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)|
|\Bbb Q(\sqrt5):\Bbb Q|$ so $|K:\Bbb Q|$ is divisible by $2$.
Similarly $|K:\Bbb Q|$ is divisible by $3$ (why?). So
it is divisible by $6$ (as $2$ and $3$ are coprime). But $|K:\Bbb Q|\le 6$
(why?).

Comment: If $|K:Q|>6$, then the minimal polynomial can't have degree 6?

Comment: @Nico that's one way to see it.